# Illegal string offset sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, plot

Been dealing with this problem for a while now and i can't figure it out.
I've read similar topics to this one but i haven't been able anyways.

I'm trying to import data from an sqlite database using php. I will be using the data to plot it. Whenever i try to run the code i get stuck at "illegal string offset".

Here is the code:

```
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }

$sql =<<<EOF
SELECT voltage from stuffToPlot;
EOF;

$voltage = array();


$ret = $db->query($sql);
while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM)) {
        $voltage[] = row['voltage'];
//var_dump($row);
}


$graph = new Graph(300,250);
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;

$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
$graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing();

$graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

$graph->xgrid->Show();
$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid");
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','D'));
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');

$p1 = new LinePlot($voltage);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->SetColor("#6495ED");
$p1->SetLegend('Line 1');
?>
?>
```

When i dump the data i get this response [Picture](http://www.ladda-upp.se/bilder/zltczhawdxetj)http://www.ladda-upp.se/bilder/zltczhawdxetj

Thnx a lot!

Comment: the error should tell you what line

Comment: `row['voltage'];` should be `$row['voltage'];` You left out the `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $voltage[] = row['voltage'];
                 ^---missing $
```

so you're using an undefined constant, which PHP "helpfully" treats as an unquoted string, so you're effectively running

```
    $voltage[] = 'row'['voltage'];
```

and using an illegal string index for this "string" - you CAN treat strings as an array and access individual characters, but only with numeric indexes.

```
$foo = 'hi mom';
echo $foo[1]; //  i
echo 'hi mom'[1]; // i
echo foo[1]; // undefined constant foo, assumed 'foo' -> o
```

Comment: Aha! So i've added the dollar sign and that leaves me with the index error as predicted. Do i have to add something in the database to index each value? Or can i do this in php directly?

Thnx a lot for your answer!

Comment: you fetched as a numeric array (`SQLITE_NUM`), so you don't have string keys, just numerica. `$row[0]` would work, or switch to associative fetch, so `'voltage'` works.

Comment: Alright so far i have changed to associative fetch and instead of using voltage ['voltage'] i have instead put a zero as suggested. The following error then hits me "Can not use scalar value as an array", i searched for it on the forum and found this explanation "the reason is because somewhere you have first declared your variable with a normal integer or string and then later you are trying to turn it into an array." But i have declared the variable voltage as an array already and not a integer and cant understand what causes the problem.

Comment: so do `var_dump($row)` to see what you received.

Comment: I receive proper values as far i can determine. array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["voltage"]=> float(4.02) } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["voltage"]=> float(4.02) } } and so forth. Is it the punctuation that causes the error? I modified my database since there were three nulls but this didn't help either.
[code] $ret = $db->query($sql);
while ($row[0] = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        $voltage[] = $row[0];
var_dump($row);
[/code]